# Error while building Bottom Navigation Bar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to learn by imitating an app so please do not bash me too hard. First of all, I have this `main_page.dart` that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3YV0.jpg). This is without the `BottomNavigationBar` and it works perfectly fine. I'm watching this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoCMM0u4oGY) to build a `bottom nav bar` but this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00lLG.jpg) occur when I try to include into my `main_page.dart` which is the `HomePage()` in my `main.dart (which is the original MAIN dart file that comes initially`.
So here's my `BottomNavigationBar` code:

```js
class bottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const bottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<bottomNavBar> createState() => _bottomNavBarState();
}

class _bottomNavBarState extends State<bottomNavBar> {
  List pages = [
    HomePage(),
    activityMain(),
    investMain(),
    sendMain()
  ];

  int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTap(int index){
      setState(() {
        currentIndex = index;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: onTap,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF36A3B),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedFontSize: 10,
        unselectedFontSize: 10,
        elevation: 0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Assets', icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wallet)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Activity', icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.userPlus)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Invest', icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowTrendUp)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Send', icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidPaperPlane))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the error, but generally there is a problem when generating a bottom navigation bar with more than thre items just define the type as fixed like so:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
...
```